# How to kill a Service by another Activity?

Tags: java, android, service, android-activity, android-intent

1. Activity 1 starts a Service, using the standard Intent.
2. Activity 1 starts Activity 2. Then, Activity 1 gets finished().
3. Now, there's only Activity 2.

How does Activity 2 kill the Service, since that Intent was generated in Activity 1? 
I don't want to pass the Intent everywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there are several different ways to start service:

1. [startService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)) - after that you need to explicitly stop service with stopService()
2. [bindService()][2] - this method allow you to manage the lifecycle of service automaticaly. So you can make service to stop after the last client said unbind();

For details check [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#servlife)

[2]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService(android.content.Intent, android.content.ServiceConnection, int)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't care about these things. Just call stopService and pass it a new Intent object.